# TrackPopupMenuEx not seeing keys inside CWinThread

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm using TrackPopupMenuEx inside a UI CWinThread,
CMonitor is derived from CWinThread

```
    monitor_ = (CMonitor *)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMonitor));
```

CMonitor::InitInstance containes

```
m_pMainWnd = new CWnd();
m_pMainWnd->CreateEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_TOPMOST, AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_DBLCLKS),
    NULL, WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 50, 50, NULL, NULL);
```

Then later I do

```
    SetForegroundWindow(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd);

auto popup_menu_flags = TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_VERTICAL;
auto menu_item = TrackPopupMenuEx(menu, popup_menu_flags, point.x, point.y, AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd, NULL);

DestroyMenu(menu);
```

The PopupMenu display correctly and I can use the mouse to select a menu item. However the arrow keys do not work.

I have used Spy++ and m_pMainWnd get messages for WM_KEYUP, VK_DOWN but nothing happens. WM_KEYDOWN is not seen.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this function will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: why do you suggest this?

Comment: I think this way you'll be able to redirect the key messages to your thread. Have you tried it?

Comment: No - the CWin is created in the same thread as CWinThread - so there is not another thread to redirect to. I did notice that when I SetForegroundWindow the focus is not set to it but it does become the foreground window ... hmm